# Subscribe on Observable triggering two times

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, rx-android

I am observing when data has successfully added in room database but I don't understand why is subscribe triggering two times

```
Observable.fromCallable((Callable<Object>) () ->
                    statisticsViewModel.addStatistics(new Statistics())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(o -> {
                        // Triggering two times
                    });
```

Comment: Could you share code of `statisticsViewModel.addStatistics()`. By the way, `Observable.fromCallable()` can produce only one `onNext` event. Are you sure that you don't create mutliple observables? May be you can share code where such construction is used.

Comment: Also why are you subscribing to a source inside a `fromCallable`?

Comment: @ConstOrVar addStatistics() is just a method that returns a long(id of the inserted row), I have the observable inside a LiveData observer so I use the data from livedata to Insert in statistics.

Comment: @akarnokd Whats the best practice and can you send me some documentations that I can understand the process in depth, Thanks.

Comment: I'd say that you could replace `fromCallable` to `defer` operator, or as you're subscribing immediately to `addStatistics` you don't even need to wrap it at all.